# How to convert a String to a Symbol in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, symbols

I need to find a way to convert any string to a symbol. If there was a function that did that, it would be something like this:

```
function toSymbol(variable) = {
//... converts var to symbol
};

//toSymbol("mySymbolString") would return: mySymbolString
```

Is there any clever way of doing this other than storing potential string to symbol mappings in a dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you mean a Symbol, as in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol   Or do you mean to a variable?

Comment: @freedomn-m i meant it in the second sense. i need it to be a variable. thanks for pointing out the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function toSymbol(variable) {
  return Symbol(variable);
};
```

Keep in mind `toSymbol("some_string") === toSymbol("some_string") // false` ( by spec. You you need to keep it in true - add memoization )

Comment: You can use global symbols by using [`Symbol.for()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for) instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I need it to be a variable.

All global variables are actually a property of `window`

eg:

```
window.abc = 123
abc == 123
```

you can also reference properties using strings, eg:

```
window["abc"] = 123
window.abc == 123
abc == 123
```

If you're using namespaces or objects, then it's just the same, eg:

```
My.Namespace["variable"]=value
My.Namespace.variable == value
```

---

This gives your example "variable":

```
window["variable"] = value
```

it's not clear what you want to do with this, but you could make it `= null` or `= {}` to use later.

Comment: I needed this once. It was some utility function meant to be used in debugging/development  on the JS console, and the utility function did an XMLHttpRequest. And you could pass an extra string variable to the utitlify function, and that then became the global variable name (global = in window) of the result of the XMLHttpRequest. And if you didn't specify the variable name, it was called result42, result43, etc. So, it's not even *that* weird wanting to do this!