# Dynamically change elasticsearch query definition

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

So I am trying to dynamically delete specific documents from elastic and would like to use one function without hard coding the name of the item I am looking for the time range in. See code below:

```
exports.cleanElastic = function(type, timeReference){
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject){
        let dataOlderThan = "now-".concat(config.amountOfData);
        elastic.deleteByQuery({
            index: 'canary',
            type: type,
            body: {
                query: {
                    range : {
                        START_TS: {
                            lte: dataOlderThan
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

As you can see 'START_TS' is the name of the date field I care about in this instance. That will not always be the case with the project. So I am trying to pass 'timeReference' or at least its' value in for where the query reads 'START_TS'. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Ryan

Comment: whats is that timeReference variable for. can you post how that json object looks.

Comment: the timeReference variable is merely a string that currently contains 'START_TS'. I hope to change it to other strings as I move forward, but it will always be just one string.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is more of javascript to convert strings to [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511572/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-symbol-in-javascript).

```
exports.cleanElastic = function(type, timeReference){
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject){
        let dataOlderThan = "now-".concat(config.amountOfData);
        elastic.deleteByQuery({
            index: 'canary',
            type: type,
            body: {
                query: {
                    range : {
                        toSymbol(timeReference): {
                            lte: dataOlderThan
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function toSymbol(variable) {
  return Symbol(variable);
};
```

In rails we use [something](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/52128aa880ff33d4b3000280) like following for this.

```
key_name = 'age'

hash = {
    name: 'john',
    key_name.to_sym => '23'
}
```